# Firebase - Allow access to user data from an anonymous function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to figure out how to do this correctly.

In Firebase I have certain user-generated content stored in `/sites/{uid}/...`. My security rules are set like that:

```
"sites": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
  }
}
```

This way each user can only access their own content. But I have an anonymous function that needs to access that content as well and update it.

What's the best way for me to give access to that function, other than making all the content public.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'anonymous function'? Something running on a sever? If that's the case, use a service account.

Comment: Thank you cartant. I overlooked that, will give it a try. If I initialize the app as a service account, will it be considered as an authenticated user? Or will it have full access to the DB regardless of security rules?

Comment: Full access regarding read and write. Presumably any validation rules still apply, but that's just a guess. You might want to ask that in a separate question if you require clarification.

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: I've just tried and it works great! Re permissions, you can select those when you create a service account. You can grant full access, write or read-only access to your service account.